# Is there an example with Area $0<F(f)<\infty$ for some transcendental entire function

Tags: complex-dynamics

It seems that there may be  example of a transcendental entire function with finite (but positive) planar area  of the Fatou set  in Eremenko-Lyubich class. However, I can't not find it in the literature for Eremenko-Lyubich class. I remember that I may see a related title without any further details in the lecture notes of Christopher Bishop of transcendental 
dynamical system, however, I can not find it in the update version of the notes
from his homepage.

I do not know whether such example have already constructed yet beyond Eremenko-Lyubich class. (I Guess it may been constructed by the method used in the paper of Eremenko and Lyubich of Examples of entire functions with pathological dynamics.)

The comments and remarks will be appreciated.

Comment: You should add that $F(f)$ is not empty. Otherwise an example is $e^z$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Oh, I forgot. Thank you, professor! Now I add the additional condition $Area(F(f))>0$ by your advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there are such examples, the simplest one is $\sin(z^3)$.
It has a stronger property that the area of non-escaping set is finite.
MR2213937 
Hemke, Jan-Martin,
Recurrence of entire transcendental functions with simple post-singular
sets. 
Fund. Math. 187 (2005), no. 3, 255–289.

Comment: Thank you, Professor！ This is really what I am looking for!